# A customer with the same email already exists

Tags: magento2, email

> A customer with the same email already exists in an associated
>   website.

I got this `error-message` after logging the customer.
Please can anyone can help me?

Comment: If guess that you will got this message when you sign up with already exits mail address. If you have tried to register with existing  mail address

Comment: ok thanks sir But my customer name does not show

Comment: you need to reindex ...

Comment: ok fine sir one more issue i got this message You added Volleyball to your shopping cart.after adding the product in cart but this message does not remove  automatically .any suggestion will be very very appreciated.